# NestJS + GraphQL + Next.js - How to implement authentication? Can I use next-auth?

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, nestjs, next-auth

I created an API using Nest.js and GraphQL. I already created an endpoint to authenticate an user and generate access and refresh tokens (JWT).

How can I integrate this with a Next.js front-end application. I'm using Next in this project just to obtain a good SEO, I don't intend to use its API routes.

I'm currently trying to use next-auth but I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Maybe next-auth was not created for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can controll user authentification with next-auth using the [credentials provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials) in you case 
what you have to do is to return JWTs and the needed informations as response from you login API to store them in next-auth session when the user logs in.

Now you have your JWTs stored in the session you just have to call these methods to access them :

1. [getSession()](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession) (from the client side)
2. [getServerSession()](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession) (from the server side)

Then send them with your requests as you used to do.

Comment: How can you handle something like refresh tokens? Where will you save it, in an http only cookie? If so it will be considered third party cookie because next.js app runs in a different domain than your nest.js server, so your nest.js backend wont be able to receive cookies from your frontend